# Requesting Solution for a problem when clock hand jumps 1 hour every 2 hours. Would like it to run smoothly though the clock face

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Good Afternoon,

We have created an analog clock that runs in the following format

28 hours = 1 day

56 minutes = 1 hour

56 seconds = 1 minute

Where in the analog 28 hour clock, the seconds run through the entire clock face for 112 ticks. Where the minute shifts when the seconds hit 56 and 112. Similarly the hour shifts gradually through a 56 hour  period. We notice that the hour hand shifts abnormally every 2 hours when the minute crosses 56 minute mark at 14.

Can anyone help us with a solution in the solving the blocker we are going through.

We are creating the above clock for our Research work in "Our Moon Life" organisation. The intentions of this Research work is to help the Science Community in creating a living condition on the Moon. We consider the entire Research work is a common property. Your help in our Research work is being accepted with the utmost respect.

Thank you very much,
Kind Regards.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);


var ms_per_sec = 0.984; // 1000
var sec_per_min = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var min_per_hr = 56; // 55.54920598892;
var hrs_per_day = 28;

// let's make our target date at some fixed distance in our own time system
const countDownDate = 1555157555171; // 5 seconds

function loop() {
  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var total_ms = (countDownDate + now);
  // from here our values are based on our own time system
  var total_seconds = (total_ms / ms_per_sec);
  var total_minutes = (total_seconds/ sec_per_min);
  var total_hours = (total_minutes / min_per_hr);
  var total_days = (total_hours / hrs_per_day);
  
  var days = Math.floor(total_days);
  var hours = Math.floor(total_hours % hrs_per_day);
  var minutes = Math.floor(total_minutes % 112);
  var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds % 112);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
      drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
      drawTime(ctx, radius, days, hours, minutes, seconds);
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (total_ms < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    return;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
 }
 loop();



function drawClock() {
  

}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fill();
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*0.95, 0,0,radius*1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius*0.08 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline="middle";
  ctx.textAlign="center";
  for(num = 1; num < 29; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 14;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius, days, hours, minutes, seconds){
   
    var hour = hours;
    var minute = minutes;
    var second = seconds;
    //hour
    hour=hours%28;
    hour=(hours*Math.PI/14)+
    (minutes*Math.PI/(14*112))+
    (seconds*Math.PI/(1568*112));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
    //minute
    minute=(minutes*Math.PI/56)+(seconds*Math.PI/(224*112));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
    // second
    second=(seconds*Math.PI/56);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
style="background-color:#333">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you calculate minutes and seconds using either 56 or 112 depending on how you are going to use them. I fixed it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kx3scug/

The only change is:

```
hour = ((second / sec_per_min + minute) / min_per_hr + hour) / hrs_per_day * 2 * Math.PI;
```

inside drawTime

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is much appreciated.